# Server.MapMath(string path) вне класса контроллера

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Хочу определить класс, который будет управлять файлами в приложении по вызову методов. Но вот только как мне получить путь к нужной папке без класса Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string path)
```

Comment: Есть способ получения ModelState, без контроллера?

Comment: @Алексей нет, нельзя, но можно передать ModelState во внешний метод `public static CheckModel(ModelStateDictionary ModelState)`