# ModelState вне класса контроллера

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Требуется получить экземпляр ModelState вне класса контроллера. Дело  классе  проверять активирован пользователь или нет, заблокирован он или нет внутри действии контроллера не очень красиво, создаётся некая зависимость, хочется убрать эту зависимость и добавить класс который будет всё это делать после вызова метода, но передавать ему ModelState тоже не красиво, хочется убрать эту зависимость. В классе у меня есть только HttpContext. Я уже задавал похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461313/server-mapmathstring-path-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), только с классом Server.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать экшен фильтр и в нем проверять

```
public class IsUserAuth : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var store = new UserStore(new DbContext());
                var userManager = new UserManager(store);
                var userId = user.Identity.GetUserId();
                filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.User = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == userId);
            }
        }
    }
```

в моем фильтре в динамическую переменную ViewBag.User заносится информация если пользователь авторизован

ипользовать так:

```
[IsUserAuth]
public class MyController: Controller
{
   .......
}
```

Теперь актуальная информация о пользователе всегда доступна через ViewBag
Через фильтры можно выполнять и другие операции

Можно так же написать свой контроллер унаследовав его от Controller, спрятать туда нужные методы на проверку если необходимо. Ну и использовать потом свой контроллер вместо стандартного